# Python Numpy Structured Array (recarray) assigning values into slices

Tags: python, numpy, slice, recarray

The following example shows what I want to do:

```
>>> test
rec.array([(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0),
   (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)], 
  dtype=[('ifAction', '|i1'), ('ifDocu', '|i1'), ('ifComedy', '|i1')])

>>> test[['ifAction', 'ifDocu']][0]
(0, 0)

>>> test[['ifAction', 'ifDocu']][0] = (1,1)
>>> test[['ifAction', 'ifDocu']][0]
(0, 0)
```

So, I want to assign the values `(1,1)` to `test[['ifAction', 'ifDocu']][0]`. (Eventually, I want to do something like `test[['ifAction', 'ifDocu']][0:10] = (1,1)`, assigning the same values for for `0:10`. I have tried many ways but never succeeded. Is there any way to do this?

Thank you,
Joon

Comment: Also see @HYRY's [answer to a slightly different question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21819324/347815) that gives a great solution to this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say `test['ifAction']` you get a view of the data.
When you say `test[['ifAction','ifDocu']]` you are using fancy-indexing and thus get a copy of the data. The copy doesn't help you since modifying the copy leaves the original data unchanged.

So a way around this is to assign values to  `test['ifAction']` and `test['ifDocu']` individually:

```
test['ifAction'][0]=1
test['ifDocu'][0]=1
```

For example:

```
import numpy as np
test=np.rec.array([(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0),
   (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)], 
  dtype=[('ifAction', '|i1'), ('ifDocu', '|i1'), ('ifComedy', '|i1')])

print(test[['ifAction','ifDocu']])
# [(0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0)]
test['ifAction'][0]=1
test['ifDocu'][0]=1

print(test[['ifAction','ifDocu']][0])
# (1, 1)
test['ifAction'][0:10]=1
test['ifDocu'][0:10]=1

print(test[['ifAction','ifDocu']])
# [(1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1)]
```

For a deeper look under the hood, see [this post by Robert Kern](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2009-February/040684.html) .

Comment: Thank you very much. So the problem was with the field access.