# How to return a view of several columns in numpy structured array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I can see several columns (`fields`) at once in a `numpy` structured array by indexing with a list of the field names, for example

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([(1.5, 2.5, (1.0,2.0)), (3.,4.,(4.,5.)), (1.,3.,(2.,6.))],
        dtype=[('x',float), ('y',float), ('value',float,(2,2))])

print a[['x','y']]
#[(1.5, 2.5) (3.0, 4.0) (1.0, 3.0)]

print a[['x','y']].dtype
#[('x', '<f4') ('y', '<f4')])
```

But the problem is that it seems to be a copy rather than a view:

```
b = a[['x','y']]
b[0] = (9.,9.)

print b
#[(9.0, 9.0) (3.0, 4.0) (1.0, 3.0)]

print a[['x','y']]
#[(1.5, 2.5) (3.0, 4.0) (1.0, 3.0)]
```

If I only select one column, it's a view:

```
c = x['y']
c[0] = 99.

print c
#[ 99.  4.   3. ]

print a['y']
#[ 99.  4.   3. ]
```

Is there any way I can get the view behavior for more than one column at once?

I have two workarounds, one is to just loop through the columns, the other is to create a hierarchical `dtype`, so that the one column actually returns a structured array with the two (or more) fields that I want.  Unfortunately, `zip` also returns a copy, so I can't do:

```
x = a['x']; y = a['y']
z = zip(x,y)
z[0] = (9.,9.)
```

Comment: An update for anyone living in the present - `a[['x','y']]` now _does_ return a view.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can create a dtype object contains only the fields that you want, and use `numpy.ndarray()` to create a view of original array:

```
import numpy as np
strc = np.zeros(3, dtype=[('x', int), ('y', float), ('z', int), ('t', "i8")])

def fields_view(arr, fields):
    dtype2 = np.dtype({name:arr.dtype.fields[name] for name in fields})
    return np.ndarray(arr.shape, dtype2, arr, 0, arr.strides)

v1 = fields_view(strc, ["x", "z"])
v1[0] = 10, 100

v2 = fields_view(strc, ["y", "z"])
v2[1:] = [(3.14, 7)]

v3 = fields_view(strc, ["x", "t"])

v3[1:] = [(1000, 2**16)]

print(strc)
```

here is the output:

```
[(10, 0.0, 100, 0L) (1000, 3.14, 7, 65536L) (1000, 3.14, 7, 65536L)]
```

Comment: Ooh, this is nice, works for non-contiguous (or irregularly spaced) fields.

Comment: New answer to an old question, @andy, doesn't get much attention that way :P

Comment: This fails if the array has any columns not supported by `memoryview`, such as datetime64.  See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4983 for details.

Comment: The result is not a numpy array anymore but a dict and won't be usable with many numpy functionalities like broadcasting.

Answer (score 11):

Building on @HYRY's answer, you could also use `ndarray`'s method `getfield`:

```
def fields_view(array, fields):
    return array.getfield(numpy.dtype(
        {name: array.dtype.fields[name] for name in fields}
    ))
```

Comment: Nice, how did we miss that? Seems cleaner and saver to avoid passing the data and strides. [`getfield`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.getfield.html) does not appear to be a [new](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.getfield.html) method, though I've never seen it before.

Comment: The result is not a numpy array anymore but a dict and won't be usable with many numpy functionalities like broadcasting.

Answer (score 7):

As of Numpy version 1.16, the code you propose *will* return a view.  See 'NumPy 1.16.0 Release Notes->Future Changes->multi-field views return a view instead of a copy' on this page:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.16.0-notes.html#multi-field-views-return-a-view-instead-of-a-copy

Comment: Only in numpy 1.16 was this feature implemented

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in 2020.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is an easy way to achieve what you want. In general, you cannot take an arbitrary view into an array. Try the following:

```
>>> a
array([(1.5, 2.5, [[1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 2.0]]),
       (3.0, 4.0, [[4.0, 5.0], [4.0, 5.0]]),
       (1.0, 3.0, [[2.0, 6.0], [2.0, 6.0]])], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('value', '<f8', (2, 2))])
>>> a.view(float)
array([ 1.5,  2.5,  1. ,  2. ,  1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  4. ,  4. ,  5. ,  4. ,
        5. ,  1. ,  3. ,  2. ,  6. ,  2. ,  6. ])
```

The float view of your record array shows you how the actual data is stored in memory. A view into this data has to be expressible as a combination of a shape, strides and offset into the above data. So if you wanted, for instance, a view of `'x'` and `'y'` only, you could do the following:

```
>>> from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
>>> b = as_strided(a.view(float), shape=a.shape + (2,),
                   strides=a.strides + a.view(float).strides)
>>> b
array([[ 1.5,  2.5],
       [ 3. ,  4. ],
       [ 1. ,  3. ]])
```

The `as_strided` does the same as the perhaps easier to understand:

```
>>> bb = a.view(float).reshape(a.shape + (-1,))[:, :2]
>>> bb
array([[ 1.5,  2.5],
       [ 3. ,  4. ],
       [ 1. ,  3. ]])
```

Either of this is a view into  `a`:

```
>>> b[0,0] =0
>>> a
array([(0.0, 2.5, [[0.0, 2.0], [1.0, 2.0]]),
       (3.0, 4.0, [[4.0, 5.0], [4.0, 5.0]]),
       (1.0, 3.0, [[2.0, 6.0], [2.0, 6.0]])], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('value', '<f8', (2, 2))])
>>> bb[2, 1] = 0
>>> a
array([(0.0, 2.5, [[0.0, 2.0], [1.0, 2.0]]),
       (3.0, 4.0, [[4.0, 5.0], [4.0, 5.0]]),
       (1.0, 0.0, [[2.0, 6.0], [2.0, 6.0]])], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('value', '<f8', (2, 2))])
```

It would be nice if either of this could be converted into a record array, but numpy refuses to do so, the reason not being all that clear to me:

```
>>> b.view([('x',float), ('y',float)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: new type not compatible with array.
```

Of course what works (sort of) for `'x'` and `'y'` would not work, for instance, for `'x'` and `'value'`, so in general the answer is: it cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

In my case 'several columns' happens to be equal to two columns of the same data type, where I can use the following function to make a view:

```py
def make_view(arr, fields, dtype):
    offsets = [arr.dtype.fields[f][1] for f in fields]
    offset = min(offsets)
    stride = max(offsets)
    return np.ndarray((len(arr), 2), buffer=arr, offset=offset, strides=(arr.strides[0], stride-offset), dtype=dtype)
```

I think this boils down the the same thing @Jamie said, it cannot be done in general, but for two columns of the same dtype it can. The result of this function is not a dict but a good old fashioned numpy array.